# Motive for question closure: "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons, migration

When we think a question would be more appropriate "on another site in the Stack Exchange network" the only possibility we are offered in the closure form is that it belongs on *meta.french.stackexchange.com*.

But some questions just don't belong to meta.french but to a completely different site, for example [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/177674/12918) that was migrated to *ELU* or [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11278/358) that I think might get more appropriate answers on
*Genealogy & Family History*.

Obviously we can always clik on *Other* and then explain. But wouldn't it be simpler instead of having a pre installed link to *meta.french* to have a box in which to insert the link to whatever other site in the Stack Exchange network we think the question could be migrated to?

---

Quand nous voulons donner comme motif de fermeture la raison que la question serait plus appropriée sur un autre autre site de *Stack Exchange* nous devons choisir le motif *off-topic* puis cocher que la question appartient à un autre site du réseau et là le seul choix pré installé est la redirection vers
*meta.french.stackexchange.com*.

Or toutes les questions qui ne sont pas au bon endroit n’appartiennent pas forcément à *meta.french* mais à un tout autre site du réseau, comme [celle-ci](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/177674/12918)
qui a été déplacée vers *ELU* ou [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11278/358) que je verrais personnellement mieux sur *Genealogy & Family History*.

Bien sûr nous pouvons choisir  *Other* et expliquer notre choix, mais ne serait-il pas plus simple de sauter une étape et d'avoir directement la case vide pour insérer le lien vers un site du réseau plutôt que le lien pré installé vers
*meta.french* ?

Answer (score 7):

[Migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) is possible. However, only moderators can migrate a question to an arbitrary site, and they can only migrate questions that are less than 60 days old.

There are two requirements for migration:

- The question must be off-topic where it is. We don't migrate questions just because it might also be on-topic elsewhere.
- The question must be a good, on-topic question by the standards of the destination site. Avoid suggesting migrations if you aren't familiar with the destination site.

Some Stack Exchange sites have predefined migration paths that appear when voting or flagging to close as off-topic. These paths are only created from a graduated (i.e. non-beta) site to a graduated site, and only when migrations are sufficiently common (multiple migrations per week). All sites, even beta sites, have such a migration path from the main site to the meta site.

French.SE rarely migrates questions away, so even if the site graduated now, we'd be very far from acquiring a migration target. Since the site started, we only migrated 13 questions (not including rejected migrations which are harder to track down:

- 6 to [English L&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/), 4 of which had to be translated from French
- 2 to [English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/);
- 2 to [Super User](https://superuser.com/);
- 1 to [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/);
- 1 to [Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/);
- 1 to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (which had to be translated).

If you see a question that you think should be migrated, then:

1. Vote or flag to close as off-topic. We don't migrate on-topic questions.
2. If necessary, translate the question into English.
3. Flag a moderator to request the migration to another site. In your flag, please indicate how confident you are that the question is suitable for the proposed destination (are you a regular there? Did you browse the meta site to see if this question type would be acceptable?).

---

Il est possible de migrer une question vers un autre site. Seuls les modérateurs peuvent le faire, et pas plus de 60 jours après que la question a été postée.

Deux conditions doivent être réunies pour migrer une question :

- La question doit être hors sujet sur ce site. Nous ne migrons pas une question seulement parce qu'elle serait aussi acceptable ailleurs.
- La question doit être une bonne question pour la destination proposée. Merci de ne suggérer une migration que si vous êtes suffisamment familier avec la destination pour savoir que la question y serait bienvenue.

Certains sites sur Stack Exchange ont des chemins de migration prédéfinis qui apparaissent lorsque l'on vote ou signale pour clore une question comme étant hors sujet. À part un chemin du site principal vers le site méta, qui existe toujours, les chemins de migration ne sont créés que d'un site non-bêta vers un site non-bêta, et seulement s'il y a un débit suffisant (plusieurs migrations par semaine).

Les migrations depuis French.SE sont rares, donc même si le site finissait sa phase bêta maintenant, nous serions loins d'acquérir un chemin de migration. Depuis le début du site, nous avons en tout et pour tout migré 13 questions, sans compter les migrations vers le site méta, ni les migrations refusées (qui sont plus difficiles à lister) :

- 6 vers [English L&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/), dont 4 ont dû être traduites du français en anglais ;
- 2 vers [English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) ;
- 2 vers [Super User](https://superuser.com/) ;
- 1 vers [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) ;
- 1 vers [Webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) ;
- 1 vers [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (qu'il a fallu traduire).

Si vous pensez qu'une question doit être migrée :

1. Voter (ou signaler) pour la clôture, au motif « off-topic » (seules les questions hors sujet mais par ailleurs acceptables pour Stack Exchange sont susceptibles d'être migrées).
2. Si nécessaire, traduire la question en anglais.
3. Signaler (« flag » → « other (needs ♦ moderator attention) » la question et demander la migration. Merci d'indiquer dans votre message de signalement votre degré de familiarité avec la destination proposée (êtes-vous un habitué du site ? Avez-vous parcouru son site méta pour savoir si les questions de ce type y sont acceptées ?).